# NotifyDataSetChanged in activity with adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

i have this in my activity:

```
    mylistCodelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            try {
                if (codeAction == 1) {

                    if (Schedario.returnNewListCode().size() == 1) {
                        Schedario.returnListDimensionList()
                                .get(Schedario.parentPosition)
                                .setChecked(false);
                    } else {
                        Schedario.returnListDimensionList()
                                .get(Schedario.parentPosition)
                                .setChecked(true);
                    }

                    Schedario.returnNewListCode().get(position)
                            .setChecked(true);

                }

                synchronized (view) {
                    view.notifyAll();
                }
```

I want that when I click on an item, the list is updated in the adapter.

I also tried to add this:

```
synchronized (mylistCodelist) {
                        mylistCodelist.notifyAll();
                    }
```

but does not work. 
how can I solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`. This will update your list view when new data has arrived.

What I grasp from your question is that when the button is clicked, you want your list to be updated based on some criteria, right?

Comment: i have try this, but gives me error :
The method notifyDatasetChanged() is undefined for the type ListView

Comment: error : The method notifyDatasetChanged() is undefined for the type ListView

Comment: @Franki You need to call it on your adapter, not on your list